# Return Array From An Event AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, events, air

I got a question that is driving me crazy. I have a DIRECTORY_LISTING event, that is executed with the files in a directory. This code is n a method o a class that only does the return a array with this informations (the code is above). How can I add a return of this array on a method in the DocumentClass that invoke and receive this value?

```
//Lista arquivos
public function listaArquivos(diretorio:File, nome_arquivo:String, 
                              lista_molduras:Array, index:int):Array {
    //Tenta fazer tudo isso
    try{
        //Seta o diretoório de molduras
        var directory = diretorio;
        directory.getDirectoryListingAsync();
        directory.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING,listaHandler);

        //Percorre arquivos
        function listaHandler(evento):void {
            //Contador
            var i:int = 0;
            //Conteúdo
            var contents = evento.files;
            for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
                var nome:String = contents[i].name;
                var nome_array:Array = new Array();
                nome_array = nome.split("_");
                //Formata para ordenar
                arquivos_animacao.push ({nome:contents[i].name,
                    tamanho:contents[i].size, ordem:nome_array[0]});
            }
            //Ordena para a ordem de númeração
            arquivos_animacao.sortOn("ordem", Array.NUMERIC);
            lista_molduras[index] = arquivos_animacao;
        }
    } catch(erro:ReferenceError) {
    }
    return lista_molduras;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to dispatch an event that has an array attached to it? If so, I can provide some example code and an explanation on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

var arListaArquivos:Array = listaArquivos();

Comment: Sorry 2smacks, but I alredy do this to receive the value, and is always null, because I have the event (listaHandler), that does not return value. If I get the peropertie from Document Class, also, is always null too, because the listaHandler is not finished yet.